# How to remove meta value in all WordPress posts?

Tags: wordpress

Am working on a blog and I want to add a banner which is a featured post.

But am not sure how can I make only one post to be marked as the "Featured" so if another post is marked as "Featured" it removes the old post from showing as featured.

I've tried using ACF (Advance Custom Field) checkbox to mark featured posts but my approach is incorrect.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
global $post;

$myposts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'numberposts'      => 1,
) );

if ( $myposts ) {
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        if(get_field('featured_post')):
?>
```

Once I marked the other posts featured nothing shows up.

Planning to follow this [approach](https://smallenvelop.com/how-to-create-featured-posts-in-wordpress/) but I have no idea on how to remove the old featured posts.

Comment: A better way to do this using ACF, is relying on the built in Options page. Create a field for the Options page called "Featured Post" or whatever. You can make it a drop down so only one post can be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ACF checkbox / True/False field is a good starting point. A solution from there on would be to...

1. hook onto the `acf/save_post` action
2. check whether the currently saved post has `featured_post` enabled
3. if enabled, unset the 'featured' flag on the previously featured post
4. if enabled, store the post's ID as a global option for the featured post ('mysites_featured_post')
5. upon rendering the banner, get the featured post's ID from this option

For the option, you can do two things: use WP's own `update_option`, or create an ACF options page with a `Post` field that contains just one (featured) post. The ACF options page has the advantage that you can manually edit the featured post in wp-admin by navigating to the options page.

However, I'll demonstrate it using WP's `update_option`:

```
function hookACFSavePost($post_id) {
  $marked_featured = get_field('featured_post', $post_id);
  if ($marked_featured) {
    // get previously featured post
    $prev_featured_post = get_option('mysites_featured_post', false);
    if (is_numeric($prev_featured_post)) {
      // disable featured flag on the previously featured post, for consistency:
      update_field('featured_post', false, $prev_featured_post);
    }
    // store this as the current featured post
    update_option('mysites_featured_post', $post_id, true);
  }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'hookACFSavePost', 20);
```

By this, we have achieved to disable the 'featured' checkbox on the previously selected post (if it existed), and stored the new featured post's ID in the 'mysites_featured_post' option.

To then get the featured post for rendering the banner, you can retrieve the `$post_id` from the option:

```
$featured_post_id = get_option('mysites_featured_post', false);
if ($featured_post_id) {
  $post = get_post( $featured_post_id );
  // render the post('s ID)
  // ...
}
```

This solution is simple and efficient in the sense that it does not have to iterate over / query all posts' meta entries to find the currently featured post.